# How to make an existing AngularJS SPA plugable to other projects

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I have an AngularJS app (myApp) currently used only by my own ASP.NET MVC app. The AngularJS is working well in my app.  Now other MVC apps also want this as an add-on (plugin).  Is this possible to do without modifying my original AngularJS app, and been too intrusive to other apps?

I thought is like this:

1. distribute the myApp.js to an in-house CDN to be included the BundleConfig.cs by other apps
2. add a <DIV data-ng-app="myApp"> in pages of other apps so that my original AngularJS can be injected.

Answer (score 0):

Far too many unknowns about how your app is configured for a precise answer but any module can be dependency injected into another module.

For simplicity sake assume that you have all the templates needed to run your app converted to javascript strings and use `$templateCache()` to register them and all the code for your app is in one file then anyone would be able to inject your module into theirs and use whatever components you have available.

All they would need would be a script tag that points at location for your app file ... and that location could be any server, cdn or local download directory